# selectonemenu does not display value from bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am having problems with the primefaces selectonemenu, it only displays cube.name (the pulldown has the verbiage cube.name not the value of cube.name), here is the code.

```
    <p:selectOneMenu id="cubeConfigId" value="#{projectModel.selectedProject.cubeConfigId}"  >
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
  <f:selectItems value="#{projectModel.cubeConfigEntities}" var="cube" itemLabel="cube.name" itemValue="cube.cubeConfigId"/>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

what exactly does the var="cube"  do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got `itemLabel="cube.name"` instead of `itemLabel="#{cube.name}"` (same for `itemValue`).

What is displayed is determined by `itemLabel="cube.name"` so you see what you got in label - in this case it's only name (if you do something like this `itemLabel="#{cube}"` - `toString()` will be displayed of the `Cube` entity). What is saved in backing bean is under `itemValue`.

`var="cube"` is just iterator for `value="#{projectModel.cubeConfigEntities}"`. If `cubeConfigEntities` is list of `Cube` entities  then `var="cube"` is `Cube` in one loop iteration, in another loop iteration it takes another `Cube` from list etc. You can access `Cube` methods by invoking them on `cube`.

Comment: Thank you it worked and thanks for the var answer.  I never thought of it as an iterator but it makes sense now.   Thanks